# TCP Sockets - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I'm new to networking in C# and I am having some troubles making a basic client - server. The server runs fine, but when the server is up and the client tries to connect it throws the error "the socket must not be bound or connected". Some extra details are that the server and client are being ran on the same computer with exclusiveAddressUse disabled.

Client code:

```
this.client = new TcpClient(this.settings.GetByName("MasterServerIP").Value, int.Parse(this.settings.GetByName("MasterServerPort").Value)) { ExclusiveAddressUse = false };
this.client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(this.settings.GetByName("MasterServerIP").Value), int.Parse(this.settings.GetByName("MasterServerPort").Value));
this.writer = new BinaryWriter(this.client.GetStream());
this.reader = new BinaryReader(this.client.GetStream());
```

Server code:

```
this.Listener.Start();
TcpClient tcpClient;
while (this.Listener.Server.Connected)
{
tcpClient = this.Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => { this.ProcessClient(tcpClient); }); //Runs the thing on another thread so this can be accepting another client
t.Start();
}
```

Edit: Even with the connect method call removed, it is still throwing the same error. Any help?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove relevant detail. It's fine to _augment_ the information but making changes that invalidate all the answers to date "breaks" the q&a concept.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought I'd remove it so people don't point that out anymore (Incase they didn't see the answers)

Comment: That's okay, just add an edit to the end of the question that it appears to error even without the second connect, and that the error is on the constructor call. And give us the actual error number from the socketexception as well :-)

Comment: user1763295, see my updated answer. It's actually to do with the exclusiveaddressuse property setting, combined with the particular constructor you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a TCPClient with the host and port, it connects automatically. You don't then need to connect again.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(v=vs.110).aspx for details.

With regards to your comment that it's still failing when you remove the connect call, either you're still running the other code or there's something else wrong. The following code runs fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace testtcp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("www.google.com", 80);
            //client.Connect("www.microsoft.com", 80);
        }
    }
}
```

but, the instant you uncomment the `Connect` call, you get a `SocketException` with the expanatory text:

```
{"A connect request was made on an already connected socket"}
```

However, that's actually a *different* error message to the one you're getting, leading us to believe the "there's something else wrong" statement from above.

If you examine the online docs for `TcpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.exclusiveaddressuse.aspx), you'll notice the following snippet (my bold):

> This property must be set before the underlying socket is bound to a client port. If you call `Connect`, `BeginConnect`, `TcpClient(IPEndPoint)`, or **`TcpClient(String, Int32),`** the client port is bound as a side effect of the method, and you cannot subsequently set the ExclusiveAddressUse property.

And indeed, the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace testtcp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("www.google.com", 80) {
                ExclusiveAddressUse = false
            };
        }
    }
}
```

gives you the *exact* exception you describe.

So, bottom line, if you *want* to use `ExclusiveAddressUse`, don't try to use it with the host-and-port constructor, since that will bind the socket and the attempted property change will then raise an exception. Instead, (as one possibility) use the no-argument constructor, change the property, and *then* connect.

Comment: Still throwing the error after removing the connect method call.

Comment: @user1763295 I suggest that isn't true. I suggest you aren't running the corrected code.

Comment: @EJP, actually it turns out it _was_ true. The error is a combination of constructor selection (one that binds) along with trying to change a property that can't be changed after binding.

Comment: You sir/ma'm are a god send, that fixed it. Your description of the problem was very well wrote aswell so I completely understand the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: This was was helpful for me using UDP Client: the solution in regard to "ExclusiveAddressUse = false" being done after using the constructor that binds to an endpoint must be done before using a UDP constructor that takes in an endpoint as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first two lines of the client code:

```
this.client = new TcpClient(this.settings.GetByName("MasterServerIP").Value, int.Parse(this.settings.GetByName("MasterServerPort").Value)) { ExclusiveAddressUse = false };
this.client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(this.settings.GetByName("MasterServerIP").Value), int.Parse(this.settings.GetByName("MasterServerPort").Value));
```

When you call to the constructor on the first line, you're already connecting the TcpClient, so the Connect call afterwards is invalid. Remove it and it will work.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the constructor:

> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and connects to the specified port on the specified host.

Comment: I removed the connect and it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Is it throwing the error on the server or on the client? And on which line?

Comment: It's throwing it on the the line where I define it (this.client = new TcpClient etc). And just to add some extra info I haven't set a value for it (private TcpClient client;)

Comment: Do you think it could be because the server is also binding to the same computer, port and ip?